# get total orders for the last 1 month every week

Tags: sql-server

I have an "Orders" table containing column CreatedDate (datetime) on when the order took place.

Today is Feb 13, 2014.

How to get total records for the last 4 weeks for every week.

it should return something like this:

```
PerDate     Total
2014-01-26  13    <--- sunday
2014-02-02  24    <--- sunday
2014-02-09  33    <--- sunday
2014-02-13  35    <--- this is today

13 from the first record is the total record from 2014-01-20 00:00:00 AM (monday) to 2014-01-26 12:00:00 PM (sunday)
24 from the 2nd record is the total record from 2014-01-27 00:00:00 AM (monday) to 2014-02-02 12:00:00 PM  (sunday)
33 from the 3rd record is the total record from 2014-02-03 00:00:00 AM (monday) to 2014-02-09 12:00:00 PM  (sunday)
35 from the 4th record is the total record from 2014-02-10 00:00:00 AM (monday) to 2014-02-13 (today)
```

so they are in Ascending order.

Comment: If the first record is from Sunday to Sunday and the second record again from Sunday to Sunday, then wouldn't Sundays get counted twice?

Comment: Why do you count from 2014-01-19? If today is 2014-02-13 then last month should begin with 2014-01-13. Or you need only last 4 weeks?

Comment: @Raj sorry i mean for each week, the "FROM" part should be Monday 00:00 AM. i have edited it.

Comment: @valex for the last record i want to count from Monday - Today total order.

Comment: @valex for the last record i want to get current total order for this week, means last monday - today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [DATEPART(dw,CreatedDate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to calculate date of begin and end of the week for each `CreatedDate` and then just group by this field:

```
WITH T AS
(
  SELECT 
       cast(floor(cast(CreatedDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,CreatedDate)+1 as BeginOfweek,        
       cast(floor(cast(CreatedDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,CreatedDate)+8 as EndOfWeek
  FROM ORDERS
  WHERE cast(floor(cast(CreatedDate as float)) as datetime) BETWEEN 
      DATEADD(WEEK,-4,GETDATE())
      AND 
      GETDATE() 

) 

SELECT 
 BeginOfWeek,
 MIN(CASE WHEN GETDATE()<EndOfWeek 
               THEN GETDATE() 
               ELSE EndOfWeek
      END) as EndOfWeek,
 Count(*) as OrdersCount
FROM T
Group by BeginOfWeek
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59e67/5)</kbd>

Comment: sorry i just edited  the post. can you pls update yours?

Comment: im using sql server 2005 btw, it returns kinda wrong
BeginOfWeek EndOfWeek OrdersCount
2014-01-13 10:32:40.523 2014-01-20 10:32:40.523 1
2014-01-13 15:50:30.573 2014-01-20 15:50:30.573 1
2014-01-13 16:33:06.880 2014-01-20 16:33:06.880 1

Is it because there is time on my CreatedDate?

Comment: @user974130 - I've changed the answer to extract only DATE part from `CreatedDate`.

Comment: sorry the BeginOfWeek column should be on Monday. and EndOfWeek should be Sunday.
your solution is almost perfect but the endofweek overlaps beginofweek. pls help

Comment: i have changed your query to
...
       cast(floor(cast(CreatedDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,CreatedDate)+1 as BeginOfweek,        
       cast(floor(cast(CreatedDate as float)) as datetime)
           -DATEPART(dw,CreatedDate)+7 as EndOfWeek
...

and it's perfect! thank you